# Customizing Django Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a Model named Attendance.

```
class Attendance(models.Model) :
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    student_name = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    instructor_name = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I pass it as a form, after selecting a particular course, I **have to select students from the entire list of students enrolled for all courses**. Instead I want to customize it such that only **students enrolled in that particular course is displayed**.

I have tried using *through fields* for student_name field but in that case I need to pass Attendance as a Foreign Key in Student model and I need to create an instance of attendance before creating an instance of a Student.

models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')

class Student(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    rollno = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default='')
    course_name = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=40, default='')

class Instructor(models.Model) :
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Also ,this is the template which contains the link to the Attendance form . I have passed the course for which attendance has to be taken as a parameter.

```
{% block content %}
      <h2>Select the course for which attendance has to be taken</h2>
      <h3><a href="{% url 'student_list' pk=clone_teacher.course_name.pk %}">{{ clone_teacher.course_name }}</a></h3>
{% endblock %}
```

I am stuck here for quite a while . Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the **init** of you ModelForm to filter the ManyToMany field.

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['student_name'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(course_name=self.instance.course_name)
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked , but the ManyToManyField is not saved in the database once entered and saved in the form.

Comment: @ShreyasShetty: Could you post the view where you are saving the form? Or maybe even better ask a new question posting the view